# A comprehension problem in Gambler's fallacy and calculating sample mean

Tags: mean, sample, heuristic, fallacy

The following problem and solution appears in *Judgment under uncertainty: Heuristics and Biases; Page 24*

> The mean IQ of the population of eighth graders in a city is *known* to be 100. You have selected a random sample of 50 children for a study of educational achievements. The first child tested has an IQ of 150. What do you expect the mean IQ to be for the whole sample?
> The correct answer is 101.

Question: how is it 101? How to arrive at that number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the given information we know that the population mean $\mu$ is equal to $100$, i.e $\mu=100$.

Then we extract a sample $n=50$, where the first child has IQ, i.e. $X_{1}=150$. And based on that we want to know what is the expected mean $\bar{X}_{50}$.

We start by taking the expected value of the sample mean $\bar{X}_{50}$

$$\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}_{50}]= \mathbb{E}[\frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{50}}{50}]=\mathbb{E}[\frac{X_{1}}{50}+\frac{X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{50}}{50}]$$

however $X_{1}$ is known so it can get outside of the expected value

$$=\frac{X_{1}}{50}+\mathbb{E}[\frac{X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{50}}{50}]$$

and inside the expected value we have to construct the sample mean but this time for only the $49$ values.

$$=\frac{X_{1}}{50}+\mathbb{E}[\frac{X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{50}}{49}]\frac{49}{50}$$

We also, know that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]=\mu$. Hence,

$$=\frac{X_{1}}{50}+100\frac{49}{50}=\frac{150}{50}+\frac{4900}{50}=101$$